# How to make CDF run using a "live version" in the browser without plugin? Is this new WRI technology?

Tags: cdf-format, cdfplayer

I was surprised to see now that some demonstrations at Wolfram web site run directly inside the browser. i.e. no need to download the CDF file and run it inside player at the computer. It runs as is.

This is new and I have not seen this before. It seems only few demons now can do this (I have links below). When going to such demo page, I see something called "Initializing live version" come up and after few seconds, one can now interact with the demonstrations directly using the browser.

Here is screen shot of one such demo

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is something great if one can use this and generate CDF for their use with this live session technology. I was trying to learn Javascript so I can port some of my demos to it so they run inside the browser directly, but if one can run CDF directly like this, then this is so much better.

**My question**: What is needed for someone to make their CDF run using live version just like the above? Is this technology only used inside WRI or is it available for users of Mathematica as well? And how does it work? Did WRI announce anything about this?

Here are links to some demos I found that uses live version

https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolvingHardTravelingSalesmanProblems/

https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivativesAndTheGradient/

https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheGeometryOfTheSteinerTreeProblemForUpToFivePoints/

But most of other demos at WRI website still do not have this feature on them for some reason.

Comment: It uses WRI's cloud stack. It's really easy to embed one of these and have it run on WRIs servers. The problem is this means that your demos will now cost you money if they have computations that get farmed out to WRI's servers. On the other hand, if you get it published as a demonstration and WRI makes a "live version" of it you should be able to link to that version directly and it won't cost you anything.

Comment: start from here https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframWebEngineForPython